# Checking if a Location is on a Bing Map

Tags: bing-maps

We could like to check if a location is on the visible Bing map but our current efforts tell  us that all locations are on the map.

After initialising the map we use the Map 'getBounds' method to return a LocationRect for the current map:

> var mapRect = MAP.getBounds();

Then we initialise a location rectangle using the value from the map:

> var rect = new Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect(mapRect);

Then carry out the check using the LocationRect method 'contains':

> alert ("result:" + rect.contains(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(38.0,
>   5.0)));

I guess it is because we are initialising the rectangle with the wrong values, some clues as to what we are doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My misunderstanding of the docs. The LocationRect should have been called with

> var rect = new Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect(mapRect.location,
>   mapRect.height, mapRect.width);